# .Net parse XML to return value of property

Tags: c#, xml

I'm always getting turned around with XML. It isn't my bag. I have a .net app that i'm trying to build to capture the needed information. Here is a sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DTS:Executable xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts">
  <DTS:Executables>
    <DTS:Executable>
      <DTS:Variables />
      <DTS:ObjectData>
        <pipeline
          version="1">
          <components>
            <component
              usesDispositions="true"
              version="4">
              <properties>
                <property
                  dataType="System.Int32"
                  description="The number of seconds before a command times out.  A value of 0 indicates an infinite time-out."
                  name="CommandTimeout">0</property>
                <property
                  dataType="System.String"
                  description="Destination"
                  name="OpenRowset">DestinationFile</property>
              </properties>
            </component>
            </components>
        </pipeline>
      </DTS:ObjectData>
    </DTS:Executable>
  </DTS:Executables>
</DTS:Executable>
```

This is just a snippet of a larger file with many DTS:ObjectData and properties per.

I'm attempting to pull the value "DestinationFile" from the property where the name = OpenRowset.

Comment: You don't mention if you are trying to read this into a object deserialized, or use json tokens, or what you're doing. Do you have any code you tried to do this with? There's tons of ways to load / parse/ process xml - and people have opinions as to the best way, so suggestions will be varied.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you're looking for is a simple [xpath](http://xpather.com/WoZmIKUx):

```
//property[@name='OpenRowset']/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into [`System.XML.XMLReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader?view=net-7.0). It's been a while since I've used it so I can't give you example code off the top of my head but the general idea is that the [`Read`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.read?view=net-7.0) function can be used to iterate through the xml nodes until you find one with `NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element` and `Name == "property"`, then [`MoveToAttribute("name")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.movetoattribute?view=net-7.0) to get the element's `name` attribute, and check if its value is `"OpenRowSet"`. If so, there's functions to get back to the attribute's parent element and read its data.